# hibernate second level cache and one to one relation

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity that I'd like to cache in the 2nd level cache, but it is updated frequently(via hibernate) and this makes it a poor candidate for the 2nd level cache.

However only 2 fields are frequently changed and the other columns are read frequently and quite static.

Is there be a benefit to move those frequently changing fields to another table and create a one-to-one relation with this new entity?  That way I could cache the original entity, now that the columns are removed, and not bother caching the new entity.  Or might any benefit gained be lost due to frequent select calls?

I know I have to do my own analysis to be sure, but I wanted to check if I'm even on a correct/sane path to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lazy loading connection between your main object and the externalized part, and you do not need the external part very often if could help.

If you need the external part very often it would not help, because you always need to access the data base any way. -- One exception would be: if your main object is very very large and you database connection very slow.

**But at least you are right: you need to test it by your own.**